# jdbc INSERT into MS Access table whose primary key is an autonumber

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc

I am trying to insert data into an MS Access database using jdbc:odbc connection from eclipse.  I am getting an error message stating:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException 4
```

I am pretty sure the issue is that I am skipping the autonumber field (first index) in the underlying table.  I figured I should skip it because Access will populate it.  So, if the underlying table has 5 fields, I create the following preparedStatement with four ?'s, attempting to reference fields 2, 3, 4, and 5.

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO someTable VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?");  
//code then populates each field, starting with index 2
ps.setString(2,"Thunder");
//...
```

My approach seems to be wrong.  However, Adding additional ?'s just seems to create other problems.  What is the correct way to write an INSERT statement into a table in an MS Access database, when the table has an autonumber primary key as its first field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The indices of `?` placeholders in your SQL string are independent from the column declarations in your table

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO someTable VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?");
```

you need to go from 1 to 4.

If you want them to match the columns, you need to specify their names

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO someTable (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?");
```

You again need to use 1 to 4 for your indices, but now you can specify which columns you are actually using.

If you want to skip the first column because it is `auto_increment`, you can do that, but you still need to start your indices at `1` and go up to the number of placeholders you have.

Comment: @CodeMed No, there is no such shorthand. The Java JDBC query code is pretty tightly coupled to your SQL schemas.

Comment: I seem to have reached a dead end on another java problem.  I have been stumbling through variations of it for a couple days now, with slow progress.  Do you have a little time to look at it and help me solve it?  I posted it in another question at this link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20307310/beancreationexception-after-adding-two-variables