# BeanCreationException after adding two variables

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Can someone show me how to get past a BeanCreationException?

I am getting a BeanCreationException after adding two variables to [Owner.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/petclinic/model/Owner.java) as follows:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "owner",  fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Pet> pets;

//I added the following two variable declarations
@Transient
private Set<Pet> cats = new HashSet<Pet>();

@Transient
private Set<Pet> dogs = new HashSet<Pet>();
```

I also added getter and setter methods for cats and dogs, along with a method for populating cats and dogs as subsets of pets as follows:

```
public void parsePets() {
    for (Pet pet : getPetsInternal()) {
    if (pet.getType().getName().equals("cat")) {cats.add(pet);} 
    else if (pet.getType().getName().equals("dog")) {dogs.add(pet);}
  }
}

protected Set<Pet> getPetsInternal() {
    if (this.pets == null) {this.pets = new HashSet<Pet>();}
    return this.pets;
}
```

The application is failing to initialize when I do Run As...Run on Server within eclipse, and is giving the following error message:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:  
Error creating bean with name  
'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0'  
defined in class path resource [spring/business-config.xml]: Initialization of bean failed;  
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:  
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource  
[spring/business-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed;  
nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException:  
[PersistenceUnit: petclinic] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory  

...  

Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException:  
Could not determine type for:  
java.util.Set, at table: owners, for columns:  
[org.hibernate.mapping.Column(cats)]
```

Here is [the code for business-config.xml](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/blob/master/src/main/resources/spring/business-config.xml).

I can eliminate the error message and get the application to run by commenting out the changes, but then I am left with the problem that the three lists (pets, cats, dogs) are identical, when I need cats and dogs to each be different subsets of pets. Here is the code which eliminates the error message but creates three identical lists which should not be identical:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "owner",  fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Pet> pets;

//I added next two variables
//    @Transient
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "owner", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Pet> cats;// = new HashSet<Pet>();

//    @Transient  
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "owner", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)  
private Set<Pet> dogs;// = new HashSet<Pet>();
```

Per axiopisty's request, I cannot really comment out everything except the addition of cats and dogs because pets, cats and dogs are called from OwnerController.java as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/owners", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String processFindForm(@RequestParam("ownerID") String ownerId, Owner owner, BindingResult result, Map<String, Object> model) {
    Collection<Owner> results = this.clinicService.findOwnerByLastName("");
    model.put("selections", results);
    int ownrId = Integer.parseInt(ownerId);
    Owner sel_owner = this.clinicService.findOwnerById(ownrId);//jim added this
    sel_owner.parsePets();
    model.put("sel_owner",sel_owner);
    return "owners/ownersList";
}
```

---

### EDIT:

As per Sotirios' request, here is my entity class, Owner.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "owners")
public class Owner extends Person {
    @Column(name = "address")
    @NotEmpty
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "city")
    @NotEmpty
    private String city;

    @Column(name = "telephone")
    @NotEmpty
    @Digits(fraction = 0, integer = 10)
    private String telephone;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "owner",  fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Pet> pets;

    //I added next two variables
    @Transient
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "owner", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Pet> cats = new HashSet<Pet>();

    @Transient
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "owner", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Pet> dogs = new HashSet<Pet>();
    //end of 2 variables I added

    public String getAddress() {return this.address;}

    public void setAddress(String address) {this.address = address;}

    public String getCity() {return this.city;}

    public void setCity(String city) {this.city = city;}

    public String getTelephone() {return this.telephone;}

    public void setTelephone(String telephone) {this.telephone = telephone;}

    protected void setPetsInternal(Set<Pet> pets) {this.pets = pets;}

    // Call this from OwnerController before returning data to page.
    public void parsePets() {
        for (Pet pet : getPetsInternal()) {
            if (pet.getType().getName().equals("cat")) {
                cats.add(pet);
                System.out.println(pet.getType().getName());
                System.out.println("cats.size() is: "+cats.size());
                System.out.println("added a cat to cats");
            } 
            else if (pet.getType().getName().equals("dog")) {
                  dogs.add(pet);
                System.out.println(pet.getType().getName());
                System.out.println("dogs.size() is: "+dogs.size());
                System.out.println("added a dog to dogs");
            }
            // add as many as you want
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");
        }
    }

    public Set<Pet> getCats() {
        System.out.println("about to return cats");
        for (Pet cat : cats) {System.out.println("counting a "+cat.getType()+" in cats.");}
        System.out.println("cats.size() is: "+cats.size());
        return cats;
    }

    public Set<Pet> getDogs() {
        System.out.println("about to return dogs");
        for (Pet dog : dogs) {System.out.println("counting a "+dog.getType()+" in dogs.");}
        System.out.println("dogs.size() is: "+dogs.size());
        return dogs;
    }

    //end section I added

    protected Set<Pet> getPetsInternal() {
        if (this.pets == null) {this.pets = new HashSet<Pet>();}
            return this.pets;
    }


    public List<Pet> getPets() {
        List<Pet> sortedPets = new ArrayList<Pet>(getPetsInternal());
        PropertyComparator.sort(sortedPets, new MutableSortDefinition("name", true, true));
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(sortedPets);
    }

    public void addPet(Pet pet) {
        getPetsInternal().add(pet);
        pet.setOwner(this);
    }

    public Pet getPet(String name) {return getPet(name, false);}

    public Pet getPet(String name, boolean ignoreNew) {
        name = name.toLowerCase();
        for (Pet pet : getPetsInternal()) {
            if (!ignoreNew || !pet.isNew()) {
                String compName = pet.getName();
                compName = compName.toLowerCase();
                if (compName.equals(name)) {
                    return pet;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new ToStringCreator(this)

            .append("id", this.getId())
            .append("new", this.isNew())
            .append("lastName", this.getLastName())
            .append("firstName", this.getFirstName())
            .append("address", this.address)
            .append("city", this.city)
            .append("telephone", this.telephone)
            .toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please update your OP with the "method for populating cats and dogs as subsets of pets". Also, if you comment out all the code that you've added, minus the additions of the @Transient cats and dogs, what happens then?

Comment: @axiopisty I put the method for populating cats and dogs in my original posting above.  I also added the processFindForm() method from OwnerController.java to illustrate why I cannot comment out everything I have added minus the additions of cats and dogs.  Do you need anything else? Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Please post your whole entity class.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I just added my entire entity class as an edit to my original posting above. What else do you need?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Did I provide you with the information that you need? I want three separately-filtered lists to be derived from the same underlying table, but I have been stumped by how to do it for a few days now.

Comment: I'm not really good with Hibernate. Can you post the full stacktrace and possibly the `Person` class?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Rather than chasing errors, I completely re-wrote another posting to describe the entire problem, including all the code that I changed, a screen shot of its unintended behavior, and a link to all the rest of the code from github.  Does this make it easier for you to see what I am doing wrong?  Please let me know.  Here is the link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20292152/parameterizing-object-properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do the seperate lists have to be instance variables?! Why not simply create a `getCats` method (and the others) and simply filter the `pets` collection? Trying to map everything makes, imho, things overly complex.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "owners")
public class Owner extends Person {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "owner",  fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Pet> pets;

    public Set<Pet> getCats() {
        Set<Pet> cats = new HashSet<Pet>();
        for (Pet pet : getPetsInternal()) {
            if (pet.getType().getName().equals("cat")) {
                cats.add(pet);
            }
        }
        return cats;
    }
}
```

Drawback is that the collection is recreated every time when needed. You can ease this with something like Google Guava and create a filter list.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "owners")
public class Owner extends Person {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "owner",  fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Pet> pets;

    public Set<Pet> getCats() {
        return Sets.filter(getPetsInternal(), new Predicate<Pet>() {
            public boolean apply(Pet pet) { 
                return pet.getType().getName().equals("cat")
            }
        });         
    }
}
```

Which you could also do inside your `parsePets` method and annotate it with `@PostLoad` so that that method would be invoked after the owner whas retrieved from the database.

Comment: And why does it need to be an instance variable? According to bean spec. a property is based on the get/set name not on the existence of an instance variable. So `getCats`  would expose a property named `cats` even if the instance variable would be called `fooBarBaz`...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest, you might use @Access(AccessType.FIELD) in your entity, it maybe solve the problem.